# I need to connect my web application to sql server using windows authentication with a different user

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, connection-string, windows-authentication

I have a web application (on IIS 7.0) developed with ASP.NET MVC 4. The application manages a database on a SQL Server 2008 R2. Only Windows Authentication is enabled on the site. In my intranet, the domain users access the program without authentication requests. `web.config` sets a connection string on the site that uses a sql user. All operations on the database are done by this last user. The application should access the database with a windows user instead of a sql user. For this,  I created a windows user “MyUser” on Sql Server. I thought I could set a new “connection string” with windows authentication but I wasn't able to pass the credential of “MyUser”. When I set windows authentication on the connection string it uses the client user, and I don't want this.

How I can operate on the database with a different user? I would like all operations on database to be performed by a single windows user (MyUser).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to SQL Server with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333287/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give "MyUser" privileges over the folder where your app is. Then you can create an application pool and set the identity to "MyUser" ([read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545795(v=cs.70).aspx)) and assign your app to this application pool.

Your application will be executing with "MyUser" account thus login into SQL with its credentials.